# How to add gcloud to path in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, gcloud, path-variables

How do you add the `gcloud` command to the path in the environment variables on Windows 10?

---

**What I've Tried**

I have gone to my Windows 10 environment variables and edited the `path` variable in `system variables`.

Here is a screenshot of what that looks like:

[image]

What's inside the `path` variable:

[image]

---

**Explanation**

I have added the path to the `/bin` folder of google cloud in the `path` variable but it does not work. Is there anything else that I am missing?

---

**Expected Results**

The environment variable for the `gcloud` command-line tool should be defined and be ready to use in the command prompt.

---

**Actual Results**

I have set inside the `path` variable this path: `C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin`, but it does not work. And the `gcloud` command is not working because of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check that the path you are using is the same used when installing, I installed my cloud sdk a while ago with default options in windows 10 and its not at program files as you mention, but in`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin`

Also my environment variable was set at installation time, maybe just by reinstalling you can set the variable right.

Comment: I installed it in my `/Program Files` location because that seems to be the most popular location for it to be in. Also, I am completely fine with that location. But I will check the file path again.

Comment: Yep, that worked! I found that the path was wrong, even though I copied and pasted it from the command prompt. Weird!